# Creating child editable textbox window on firebreath plugin

Tags: c++, winapi, plugins, firebreath, childwindow

Newbie to Winapi.Learnt the basics of winapi and tips of creating child window in firebreath plugin.
Searched tutorials,got answers.But don't know What Am i Doing wrong here? Following is my code>>My main objective is to create a textbox functioning like that in MSWord on aparent plugin(windowed firebreath plugin) window handle whereby I can edit,modify the text as well as move and resize the textbox.Also, I am not able to fire many events like WM_LBUTTONDOWN and more on the child window.

```
int WINAPI childwindow::LoadForm()
{
    HWND pluginWnd=win->getHWND();
    HINSTANCE pluginInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(pluginWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
    HWND demoWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"),TEXT("text to be written"),WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
        ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|WS_BORDER|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL, 10, 10, 300, 100, pluginWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, pluginInstance , NULL);

    //SUBCLASSING=============REFERENCE>>(http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/148771-subclassing-edit-box.html)
    PreviousSubclassedEditProc=(WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(demoWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);//WNDPROC PreviousSubclassedEditProc;
    SetWindowLong(demoWnd, GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)&childwindow::CustomWinProc);
    SetWindowText(demoWnd,_T("LALALA"));
    //======================
    ShowWindow(demoWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(demoWnd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK childwindow::CustomWinProc( HWND chWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    HWND textBoxInput,button,tempHandle=0;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(chWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                return 0;
                break;
            }
        case WM_MOUSEACTIVATE:
            {
                SetFocus(chWnd);
                break;
            }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                dragWindow = true;
                tempHandle=SetCapture(chWnd);
                break;
            }
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                tempHandle=NULL;
                dragWindow = false;
                break;
            }
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            {
                if(dragWindow==true)
                {
                    RECT mainWindowRect;
                    POINT pos;
                    int windowWidth, windowHeight;

                    pos.x = (int)(short) LOWORD(lParam);
                    pos.y = (int)(short) HIWORD(lParam);

                    GetWindowRect(chWnd,&mainWindowRect);
                    windowHeight = mainWindowRect.bottom - mainWindowRect.top;
                    windowWidth = mainWindowRect.right - mainWindowRect.left;

                    ClientToScreen(chWnd, &pos);
                    SetWindowPos(chWnd, NULL, pos.x, pos.y, windowWidth,windowHeight, SWP_NOZORDER);
                    ShowWindow(chWnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                }
                break;
            }
        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
            {
                LPCWSTR buffer[1024];
                SendMessage(chWnd,
                    WM_GETTEXT,
                    sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                return DefWindowProc(chWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
            }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The above child window is being made on a parent windowed firebreath plugin handle.
I also want to get the text from the child textbox window.but that's not possible till I get this right.I saw [one google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebreath-dev/mSJwgm1ytwI/ZMXdpjx2XFcJ)tutorials and this which has helped me a lot to get the basics.But the above problem is bugging me from last day.
Any takers for this question?

Comment: Your childwindow::LoadForm function will never returns (or, sort of) as you enter the message loop. Is that intended?

Comment: @manuell. I saw many tutorials do that. I know it is unnecessary . it's not intended.i returned EXIT_SUCCESS alternatively

Comment: Drop the message loop and return after child window creation. What problem do you have, exactly?

Comment: My test edit box is being shown but not allowing us to write text on it. The caret is not shown

Comment: Try removing your WM_NCHITTEST processing. Why do you want to return HTCAPTION?

Comment: Ok so  where to put the code Of MoveWindow()...Do you suggest WM_LBUTTONDOWN? Also I tried removing WM_NCHITTEST. Still the caret is not seen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43989/discussion-between-gotovoid-and-manuell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `RegisterClass` for "EDIT" and hope that your class will magically behave like an "Edit". You have two solutions:

**First one**: drop your Class Registration Code and use "Edit" (or `WC_EDIT`) as Class Name in `CreateWindowEx`.

**Second One**: use [GetClassInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633578.aspx) to query the Windows "Edit" class informations, and use the Window Procedure from the class (`lpfnWndProc`) in place of `DefWindowProc`.

If you choose the fisrt solution, you can provide your own Window Procedure with [subclassing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx):

As for moving/resizing a Child Window, provided that you have the hWnd, use either [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) or [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534.aspx).

Comment: I followed the first option. I subclassed the window. Now I am able to move the window by using window mousedown,move and up movements, but the text caret has gone now. Please have a look at my edited code.

Comment: You forget to return to PreviousSubclassedEditProc instead of DefWindowProc